# how fetch recent unfollowers from instagram api?

Tags: nofollow, instagram-api

[justunfollow.com](http://justunfollow.com) have a system for show recent [instagram](http://instagram.com) followers and **unfollowers** , 
**instagram api** just give me followers and following **informations** but we cant access 
for relations date info for each user ( follow and un follow ) by instagram api .
now my question is , how [ustunfollow.com](http://justunfollow.com) work ?

Comment: did you find any solution to this?