# Detect Recent Unfollowers on Instagram

Tags: instagram-api

How detect recent unfollowers on instagram

Istagram Api dont give us who persions unfollows us , but we want to know recent unfollowers

How ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how fetch recent unfollowers from instagram api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101918/how-fetch-recent-unfollowers-from-instagram-api), posted by the same user

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you might want to check Instagram's Terms of Service to check if you are allowed to do this.

An obvious way of doing this would be saving a list of all the followers and comparing this list with the previously saved one. That will tell you what the changes are including who unfollowed and in which interval it happened.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @zisoft I don't see a problem here. The first paragraph may be a comment, but the second one is a perfectly valid approach to the problem.

Comment: how do you handle the situations if the user has 100k followers? Is it possible to get the entire list everytime?